# Can a single button do different things?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two buttons to do two actions, is it possible to have only one button that should change the text and the actions that it does?

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.stopFunction()}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTesto}>STOP</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.startFunction()}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTesto}>START</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So the first time is Start, when the user clicks, the button launch the startFunction and change the text in Stop.

Comment: Yes of course; just use an expression based on state. For instance use this as text: `{ this.state.running ? "STOP" : "START" }`

Comment: Ok and to choose what actions to do??

Comment: `{() => this.state.running ? this.stopFunction() : this.startFunction()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a state variable, and then you can use *conditional rendering* based on value of the variable. Like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} 
  onPress={() => {this.state.flag ? this.stopFunction() : this.startFunction()}}
>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTesto}>{this.state.flag? "STOP" : "START"}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: and I should declare a flag in the state?

Comment: Yes declare `flag` inside state. Do not forget to set it `false` inside `stopFunction`, and `true` inside `startFunction`. @Jack23

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a state variable running

```
this.state = { running : true }
```

Now Inside your render method get the state data :

```
const { running } = this.state
```

your button should look like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.uniqueFunction()}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonTesto}>
      { running ? 'STOP' : 'START'} 
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now your unique function have to do the two actions depends on application running status:

```
uniqueFunction = () => {
    const { running } = this.state
    if( running ) {
       // The action you want to do when start button is pressed
    }else
      // The action you want to do when stop button is pressed

}
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to put everything inside a single function.

Comment: <Text style={styles.buttonTesto}>
      { running ? 'Start' : 'Stop'} 
  </Text>
When I click on start the button doesn't change to stop

Comment: @Jack23 it means that you h've omit to pass running to false when click on start button, when the running value change at render the text value have to change too

Comment: @user9408899, if the logic is just to toggle an state variable YES, why not.